# PDF is printed in text to browser instead of downloaded

Tags: php, pdf, download, http-headers, php-5.3

I'm working on a legacy app running php 5.3 and for some reason on production server PDF files are printed in gibberish straight to the browser instead of being downloaded.

[image: Gibberish printed in browser]

Nothing was changed and in development everything still works fine.

For some reason in prod server, the response is still returned with  `Content-Type: text/html`.

Here is the code:

```
public function downloadPdf($file) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="FILENAME.pdf"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize("$file"));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
        exit();
}
```

I've read numerous tutorials and questions here on Stack Overflow but nothing worked in my case.

I've tried changing:
`Content-Type: application/pdf` to `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`

`Content-Disposition: attachment;` to `Content-Disposition: inline;`

Checked if file can be read with `is_readable()` and it is.

Changed `readfile($file);` to `echo file_get_contents($file)`

With and without `exit()`

Tried adding `ob_clean()` and `flush()` before setting headers.

Nothing worked for me. Am I missing something? I can't wrap my head around that every thing is working on dev server although everything is identical.

Comment: Have you checked what headers are _actually_ being output by the server when this happens? Use your browser's developer tools to check...presumably something is different in the environment which is making it not do what you expected.

Comment: Yes, you are right and I forgot to mention, that indeed the response is a bit different. In dev it is the same as requested `Content-Type: application/pdf` but in prod it's changed to `Content-Type: text/html`. But still I have no clue why this happens.

Comment: What about the rest of the headers, are they present? Is proper PHP error reporting enabled, and did you check what the error log has to say?

Comment: I've checked the error log, and yes, it seems that some other function is sending headers before I'm setting them in the PDF download. Thank you for your help.